# How to get a stream of audio (lets say in WAV format) in spring boot server

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-21

I use Spring Boot 3.2.2 and I created the following API:

```java
@PostMapping("echo")
public ResponseEntity<?> echo(@RequestBody InputStream in) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException {
    System.out.println("Starting!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    try (AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(in);
         Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip()) {
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.start();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

For being able to test that I can play the received audio. (eventually I plan to build a sort of walkie talkie server that will be able to transfer audio stream between 2 clients)
I send the server the audio stream via the following code:

```java
public class AudioRecorder {
    private static final HttpClient HTTP_CLIENT = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

    //audio/wav
    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException, LineUnavailableException, IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {
        // Get a target data line
        try (TargetDataLine targetLine = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(new AudioFormat(8000, 8, 1, true, true))) {
            // Open the target data line
            targetLine.open();
            // Start capturing audio
            System.out.println("Recording...");
            targetLine.start();

            Thread.startVirtualThread((ThrowingRunnable) () -> {
                // Record audio for 5 seconds
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                // Stop capturing audio and close resources
                targetLine.stop();
                targetLine.close();
                System.out.println("Stopped");
            });
            // Write captured audio data to a file
//          AudioSystem.write(
//                  new AudioInputStream(targetLine),
//                  AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE,
//                  Path.of(Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().getRoot().toString(), "Users", "<user-name>", "IdeaProjects", "test", "recorded-audio.wav").toFile()
//          );


            final HttpResponse<Void> httpResponse = HTTP_CLIENT.send(
                    HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                            .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:8080/echo"))
                            .header("Content-Type", "audio/wav")
                            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofInputStream(() -> new AudioInputStream(targetLine)))
                            .build(),
                    HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.discarding()
            );
            System.out.println("Got status code: " + httpResponse.statusCode());
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it seams that spring boot doesn't call `echo` method, and in addition, on the client side, it stuck on the `send` method and doesnt reach to the printing command.
How can I improve this?
in the future I also want to make it reactive.

By the way, `ThrowingRunnable` comes from https://github.com/ashr123/exceptional-functions

Comment: What does the `System.out.println("Got status code: " + httpResponse.statusCode());` print?

Comment: @dan1stiscrying it doesn't reach this command, the code doesn't return from the `send` command